# model frame default error variable lengths differ for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I am new to R and I am trying to create a logit model. I created a train and test set for my data and when I am trying to create a logit model, I keep getting the following error message:

```
model <- glm(mortDefault2001$default ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = mortDefault2001$default ~ .,
                   data = train,:variable lengths differ (found for 'creditScore')
```

What am I doing wrong/what can I do to fix this to run the model?

This is the code I used to create the test and train sets:

```
data <- subset(mortDefault2001,select=c(1,2,3,4,6))
train <- data[1:80000,]
train <- data[1:80000,]
test <- data[80001:99999,]
model <- glm(mortDefault2001$default ~.,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)

Error in model.frame.default(formula = mortDefault2001$default ~ ., data = train,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'creditScore')
```

Comment: I checked the edit and might have approved it but there is still a major flaw with this questions: no data. Voting to close. My vote can always be rescinded if you post data that resembles whatever is in `mortDefault2001`.

Comment: model <- glm(default ~., family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train)  # use this dont use $ while using regression model as you are already specifying data set in the last